# Finding Powers of Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have been trying to work on this question and this up to were I was able to go, but I am stuck and I do not know if I am going the right way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: From $x-y=c$ and $y-z=c,$ we *cannot* conclude that $x-z=c.$ However, we *can* we conclude that $x-z=2c.$ (Hence, we can only conclude that $R$ is transitive if $2c=c$--that is, if $c=0$.) There are a few nice ways to see this. The simplest by far (and the easiest to generalize so that you can prove things about $R^i$ in general) is to note that $$x-z=x-y+y-z=c+c=2c.$$ Alternatively, note that $x=y+c$ and $y=z+c,$ so $x=(z+c)+c=z+2c,$ so $x-z=2c.$ So, we see that:

- $(x,y)\in R$ if and only if $x-y=c$
- $(u,v)\in R^2$ if and only if $u-v=2c$

Does this give you any inkling of what we can say about $R^i$ for $i\ge 1$ in general?

Also, it is more saying that $(x,z)\in R^2$ is the same as saying $$\exists y\::(x\:R\:y\wedge y\:R\:z).$$ Saying $$(\exists y\::x\:R\:y)\wedge(\exists y\::y\:R\:z)$$ is the same as saying that $x$ is in the domain of $R$ and that $z$ is in the range of $R$. In general, this need not imply that $(x,z)\in R^2$ (though it is certainly implied by it, and the implication certainly holds true for this particular relation $R$). You have a similar problem with the two statements that follow it. They are both equivalent to your erroneous statement, but not to the statement $(x,z)\in R^2$.

Comment: I do not understand how to get the solution. The only thing I can conclude is that x+z=2y

Comment: But what is $x-z$? (**Hint**: What can you do with $x-y$ and $y-z$ to get $x-z$?)

Comment: Is it by the transitivity that we can conclude that x-z?

Comment: Forget about the relation for a moment (it isn't transitive, anyway, unless we know something *very specific* about $c$), and consider the numbers $x-y$ and $y-z.$ What can we do with those two *numbers* to get the number $x-z$?

Comment: If we let y=z and substitute into x-y we would get x-z?

Comment: We can only let $y=z$ if we know that $y-z=0,$ meaning that $c=0.$ This has not been given to us, so we can't do that.

Comment: In fact, $R$ will be a transitive relation *if and only if* $c=0.$ (This would be the "very specific" thing I mentioned.)

Comment: Then x-z = 2c, the system asked me to go in chat mode.

Comment: Yes! That's it exactly. I have added to my answer. (Apologies for the chat mode. I hit the wrong button by accident.)

Comment: Ok, now if I understood we can get that R^3 would then be y-z=c that we can get from x-y=c and x-z=2c.

Comment: Not quite. Work it the same way you worked $R^2,$ noting that $R^3=R^2\circ R$. (Is that notation familiar to you?)

Comment: I looked in my notes, it means a composition of R and R^2 to get R^3. Does it mean combining x-y=c and x-z=2c to find another relation.

Comment: In principle, yes. In practice, no. It makes a difference what variables we use. What does it mean when we say that $(x,z)\in R^2\circ R,$ given what you now know about $R$ and $R^2$? (**Hint**: There exists some $y$ such that....)

Comment: There exist some y such that x R^2 z and y R z

Comment: Okay, let's step back more generally. If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are relations, what does it mean when we say that $(x,z)\in R_1\circ R_2$? Check your definition of relation compositions.

Comment: There exist some y such that (x,y)is an element of R1 and (x,z) that is an element of R2. R1=R and R^n+1 = R^n o R for n>1

Comment: That doesn't work. We *do* want $(x,y)\in R_1,$ yes, but we need something else to be an element of $R_2.$ Read the definition *very carefully*.

Comment: (y,z) in R2, then.

Comment: That works (though it disagrees with the [standard convention for definition of relation composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)#Operations_on_binary_relations)). So, when we say that $(x,z)\in R^3=R^2\circ R,$ we mean that there exists some $y$ such that $x\:R^2\:y$ and $y\:R\:z,$ meaning that $x-y=2c$ and $y-z=c.$ What is $x-z,$ then?

Comment: x=y+2c and y=z+c therefore x-z=3c

Comment: Bingo! So, you can say that $(s,t)\in R^3$ if and only if $s-t=3c.$ Are you picking up on the pattern?

Comment: Yes, I think so. (a,b) in R4 if and only if a-b=4c

Comment: Absolutely. If you want to prove it by induction, then you can perform the induction step in basically the same way that you did above. $(x,z)\in R^{n+1}$ if and only if there is some $y$ such that $x\:R^n\:y$ and $y\:R\:z,$ so that $x-y=nc$ and $y-z=c,$ and so....

Comment: Well done! Glad you stuck with it! As for me, I'm signing off for the night.

Comment: well thank you very much for your help. I do not know if you have time. I need to tell if R is an equivalence relation and If R* is also an equivalence relation. Can you give me an easy definition for an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

$(x,y)\in R^i$ if and only if $\exists x_1,x_2,x_3\ldots,x_{i+1}$ with $x=x_1$ and $y=x_{i+1}$, and $(x_j,x_{j+1})\in R$ for each $1\leq j\leq i$.

Comment: Would this be applied to the relation xRy if and only if x-y=c? I do not understand how to get this.